# How to pivot non numeric value and cross join in python or pyspark or SQL

Tags: python, sql, pandas, pivot

I have a very complicated problem.
Here is a sample of my table

```
country     data_type   data_value    value
USA         aaa         1             0.5
USA         aaa         2             1
USA         aaa         3             1.5
USA         bbb         4             2
USA         bbb         5             2.5
USA         bbb         6             3
USA         ccc         zz            3.5
USA         ccc         xx            4
CAN         aaa         1             5
CAN         aaa         2             5.5
CAN         aaa         3             6
CAN         bbb         4             6.5
CAN         bbb         5             7
CAN         bbb         6             7.5
CAN         ccc         zz            8
CAN         ccc         xx            8.5
```

Here is what I want the result to be

```
country  aaa  bbb  ccc  aaa_value  bbb_value  ccc_value
USA      1    4    zz   0.5        2          3.5
USA      2    4    zz   0.5        2          3.5
USA      3    4    zz   0.5        2          3.4
CAN      1    4    zz   5          6.5        8
CAN      2    4    zz   5          6.5        8
CAN      3    4    zz   5          6.5        8
.....
```

I've tried

```
pivot_table(
    index='country',
    columns = 'data type',
    values = ' data_value',
    aggfunc=lambda x: '   '.join(x)
)
```

But this does not give me what I want.

I prefer to solve it in python or pyspark. But SQL is ok too.

The value in aaa_value is just the value in the 'value' column

Thank you!

Comment: Can you explain what column aaa, bbb, aaa_value etc should have after pivoting ?

Comment: You would need to give an explanation of your logic. It is almost  impossible to retro-engineer the operation that you expect.

Comment: The value in aaa_value is just the value in the 'value' column